# How to retrieve the breadcrumb with REST Api

Tags: sharepoint-online, client-object-model, rest, breadcrumb

All, People who have worked on `SharePoint 2007` and `SharePoint 2010` will notice that breadcrumb is missing in the SharePoint 2013(BTW, Why Microsoft want to remove it in the `SharePoint 2013`?). But I knew there is a way to bring it back in the `SharePoint 2013`.
Says [this](http://academy.bindtuning.com/lets-bring-the-breadcrumb-back-to-sharepoint-2013/).

I had succeeded to display breadcrumb in the page.

[image]

But My question is How can I get the breadcrumb information of `List`, `Library` or `Page` with `REST API` Or `CSOM` from the SharePoint 2013?

**Updated**

It seems the breadcrumb doesn't show correctly. Why the "Site Contents" level is missing ?

[image]

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/116393/get-links-from-sharepoint-2013-global-navigation-using-rest

Comment: @Aanchal, If I opened the a certain of `List`which shows in my screen shot. I think the breadcrumb of it will be shown as `xxx site > site contents > xxx list`?  Is that true the second level will be always `Site Contents`?

Comment: No it should never include site contents if you are not on that specific page (watch the URL structure)

Comment: @RobertLindgren Forgive I am a just newbie in `SharePoint`. Don't all the list (says `Pages` in the site contents) be navigated from `Site Contents`(because you have to enter into the "Site Content", then can go the specified list page )? Why "site contents" isn't included in the breadcrumb. It doesn't make sense.. right ?

Comment: Well, you can navigate to list with site contents, but they are not logically stored beneth that page. Also, for example when it comes to pages libraries, and document libraries on team sites, you will have other ways (easier ways like a webpart on the landing page) to get to the list directly

Comment: @RobertLindgren So the breadcrumb sounds like the logical site map of SharePoint 2013 `List , Libaray, Pages` etc. Right ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that, but it reflects the logical architecture in that it shows you the Site -> Web -> SubWeb -> List -> Folder structure of SharePoint

Comment: @RobertLindgren Sorry for my ignorance in SharePoint. But I got what you mean. So the Aanchal's link is not building the BreadCrumb. It seems like try to get the menus and sub menus of Site. Right ? thanks.