# Get Global Nav using http get method

Tags: 2013, angularjs, global-navigation

How can I get global navigation into my `angularApp` using `$http`get method in angularJs.

Does sharepoint store global navigation in any List? Then I can get it by using `$http get` method.

I tried @gautam's answer/code but it's didn't work for me, I got following data

```
[{
  "CustomProperties": {
    "__metadata": {
      "type": "Collection(SP.KeyValue)"
    },
    "results": []
  },
  "FriendlyUrlSegment": "test-1",
  "IsDeleted": false,
  "IsHidden": false,
  "Key": "2e0787a2-773d-418f-90e1-03a903c08563",
  "Nodes": "__metadata": {
    "type": "Collection(SP.MenuNode)"
  },
  "results": []
  },
  "NodeType": 1,
  "SimpleUrl": "",
  "Title": "Test 1"
}]
```

Comment: Can you have a look at this question, please? http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/116393/get-links-from-sharepoint-2013-global-navigation-using-rest

Comment: I saw this link before, but the problem is I don't know `ajax`, I can only use `angularjs`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the global navigation in angular like below:

```
var myAngApp = angular.module('SharePointAngApp', []);  
myAngApp.controller('spController', function ($scope, $http) {  
    $http({  
        method: 'GET',  
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/navigation/menustate?mapprovidername='GlobalNavigationSwitchableProvider'",  
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" }  
    }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {  
        $scope.results = data.d.MenuState.Nodes.results;  
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {  

    });  
});
```

Comment: example for the Angular View for the code above: <ul ng-repeat='nav in results'><li> <a ng-href='{{nav.SimpleUrl}}'>{{nav.Title}}</a> </li></ul>

Comment: Tried your code but didn't get navigation links

Comment: @gautam I have updated my Question, Please take a look..

Comment: Your code worked when I updated `'GlobalNavigationSwitchableProvider'` to `'GlobalNavigation'`.